# Was I wrong to down vote this answer?

Tags: discussion, downvoting

I [down voted and answer on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651683/how-to-install-software-in-terminal-in-one-line-and-one-time/651694?noredirect=1#comment936190_651694), you can read the comments as too why.

This user proceeded to trawl through my history and try to find ways to get me to change my vote based on another answer that I gave (which has +12 I might add) and was updated may times based on OP comments, this really annoyed me as the user won,t address my issue and is trying to just go "gotcha" and hope I change my vote.

This is very annoying, so, rather than keep arguing with the user I thought I would get other users opinions.

So the question is, was I wrong to down vote there answer ?

What would you do ?

I just can't see how the answer in any way addresses the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As always: this is MY opinion.

The method posted by ATR could have been my answer.

1. chaining commands with `&&` is all fine but it becomes rather annoying to read.
2. putting commands in a text file and executing it is better readable plus you can keep the commands identical to how someone posted them on the web.

> How i can put all this in the terminal in one shot?

Executing a script is a "1 shot" so to me it is an answer. It is a different interpretation to the chaining with `&&` but the end result is the same: 1 command to execute lots of instructions.

Your behaviour though seems to be crossing a few lines. [The help states in the "be nice" section](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice) ...

> Rudeness and belittling language are not okay. Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.
>
> Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions. Don't expect new
>   users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they
>   learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others
>   to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well
>   to demands for help.

and ...

> Don't be a jerk. These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
> - Name-calling. Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").

Are you?

2  examples from comments in this topic in meta ...

"I will ask this one last time for you HOW DOES A SHELL SCRIPT ADDRESS THE QUESTION, "How to install software in terminal in one line and one time?" I don't care about your hypothetical, **ust answer the bloody question or shut up.**"

That is not your call.

"Still did not answer my question, did you, so you know your wrong, stop being an idiot."

Sorry?!

---

Even if you would be correct in downvoting your subsequent behaviour is seriously lacking what I would consider to be from an upstanding user.

Sorry if this in any way ticks you off. But that is how I see it ;)

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the question and answer are both irrelevant. You acted way out of line, were very rude and very aggressive. Here are some of the comments you left (emphasis mine):

> The difference her is that the question was UPDATED to include that he only need GUI not CLI AND I updated my answer to include one, my answer addresses his need for bar code readers, your answer does not in ANY WAY address "How to install software in terminal in one line and one time?". **Are you so butthurt** by my down vote that you are trawling through my history to try and trap me so I change my vote ? **Thats quite pathetic and is just silly**, the only way I will change my vote is if you stop dodging the issue and answer "How does a shell script in any way answer this issue ? "

*Butthurt*? *Pathetic*? Really?

You then brought the fight to meta with the following comments on ATR's answer here (emphasis mine):

> First im no expert this is a user forum not professional help. This is apathetic attempt to be little me as you know nothing about me, |**I did not want an argument** but you just won't let it go, sorry buy bad answers are down voted here. You keep saying "If the questioner works in server client concept as me, he find it very useful" **WTF** does this have to do with "How to install software in terminal in one line and one time?" **NOTHING, stop trying to excuse your lack of a good answer by winging about it**, all you had to do was edit more information into it an I would of changed my vote.

The only person I see wingeing (or whining, not sure which one you mean) is you. You're the one who brought this to meta. As for not wanting an argument, that's really strange considering the lengths you went to in order to get into one. Had you truly wanted to avoid an argument, you would have left this whole mess alone. But no, you went on to post:

> I will ask this one last time for you HOW DOES A SHELL SCRIPT ADDRESS THE QUESTION, "How to install software in terminal in one line and one time?" I don't care about your hypothetical, just answer the bloody question or shut up.

Again with the SHOUTING and "just answer the bloody question or shut up"! And then:

> Still did not answer my question, did you, so you know your wrong, **stop being an idiot**.

I can't believe you actually had the gall to complain about someone else when you're behaving like this. What you are doing is trolling, pure and simple and it is not acceptable behavior. I don't care if the answer in question gave a recipe for brownies. There is simply no excuse for abusing other users in the way you did here.

---

Since you asked about the specific answer, of course it answers the question! Combining commands in a shell script is a classic way of doing things in one go. Instead of running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator unity-tweak-tool variety
```

as separate commands, the OP could simply run `scriptname.sh` and get it done in one command. Now, you could have made some constructive criticism. For example:

- The `;` is not needed in shell scripts when commands are on different lines.
- This could be improved by removing the `sudo` from the script and running the script itself as `sudo scriptname.sh`.

There are various useful comments you could have made. Instead, you chose to insult and attack the person who posted an answer because their answer did not meet your criteria. As if that weren't enough, you came here to complain about how, despite your being incredibly rude and aggressive, the OP had the temerity to disagree with you. Please!

In the future, if you believe you have a valid point to make, make it *politely* and *walk away* if the OP disagrees. Even if you're right, shouting and insulting people automatically makes you wrong and is, at the very least, counterproductive.

Answer (score 3):

I believe sharing the knowledge and supporting others is a great thing. If the questioner works in server client concept as me, he find it very useful because I also made shell script to install all packages and applications in client systems after a fresh install. I have copied that script to a path in server. I copy that script in clients and run it. I have shared what I know. If that's a wrong thing I am willing to change anything I have posted because I am an Ubuntu enthusiastic and not at all a expert like @mark kirby. If I have studied something, it was by trial and error method.